# Deep Learning model (LSTM) predicts same class label

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to solve the Spoken Digit Recognition task using the LSTM model, where the audio files are converted into spectrograms and fed into an LSTM model after doing Global Average Pooling. Here is the architecture of it

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()

#input layer
input_= Input(shape = (64, 35))

lstm = LSTM(100, activation='tanh', return_sequences= True, kernel_regularizer = l2(0.000001),  
recurrent_initializer = 'glorot_uniform')(input_)

lstm = GlobalAveragePooling1D(data_format='channels_first')(lstm)

dense = Dense(20, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = l2(0.000001), kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform')(lstm)

drop = Dropout(0.8)(dense)

dense1 = Dense(25, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer = l2(0.000001), kernel_initializer= 'he_uniform')(drop)

drop = Dropout(0.95)(dense1)

output = Dense(10,activation = 'softmax', kernel_regularizer = l2(0.000001), kernel_initializer= 'glorot_uniform')(drop)

model_2 = Model(inputs = [input_], outputs = output)

model_2.summary()
```

Having summary as -
[image: Spoken Digit model]

I need to calculate the F1 score to check the performance of the model, I have implemented a custom callback and used TensorFlow addons F1 score too. However, I won't get the correct result, for every epoch I get the constant F1 score value.

On further digging, I found out that my model predicts the same class label, for the entire epoch, whereas it is supposed to predict 10 classes in one epoch. as there are 10 class label values present.

Here is my model.compile and model.predict commands. I have used TensorFlow addon here -

```
from tensorflow import keras
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001, clipnorm=0.8)

model_2.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt, metrics = metric)

hist = model_2.fit([X_train_spectrogram], 
                   [y_train_converted],
                   validation_data= ([X_test_spectrogram], [y_test_converted]),
                   epochs = 10,
                   verbose =1, 
                   callbacks=[tensorBoard_callbk2, ClearMemory()],
                   #  steps_per_epoch = 3,
                   batch_size=32)
```

Here is what I mean by getting the same prediction, the entire array is filled with the same predicted values.

[image: model.predict(test_data)]

Why is the model predicting the same class label? or How to rectify it?

I have tried increasing the number of trainable parameters, increasing - decreasing batch size too, but it won't help me. If anyone knows can you please help me out?

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with the problem you're facing, but the Dropout layers seem a bit aggressive (drop of 80% and 95% of neurons). Maybe it's worthwhile to try to lower the dropout rate.

Comment: Actually, I was getting huge loss values (four-digits) and it was also overfitting, adding a huge drop out helped in reducing the overfitting problem, and adding clip norm = 0.5 helped to get it to around 2 point something value.